# openlayers 3: don't zoom in outside the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

I'm using openlayers to create a map of a body. It shows the mri-scan of a person en on there are a lot of markers.

Totally zoomed out, there's a lot of whitespace (or in my case black space as the background is black) I've set up openlayers with the extent parameter, so users are not able to pan further than the image is big. **However** when the user hovers over the whitespace around it, and scrolls to zoom, the image is zoomed into based on the position of the cursor, so the body is out of view. Once the user starts panning again, the extent comes in to play and jumps back to the edge of the image.

Is there a way to disable zooming in/out when the cursor is outside the extent? Or if that is not possible, how can I trigger a move/pan so it jumps automatically to the edge of the image?

EDIT 14/12/2016: Created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r31nt3du/1/) to illustrate the issue.

And the code that is running there:

```
var pbm = {};
pbm.vars = {};

pbm.vars.extent = [0, 0, 1536, 5120];
pbm.vars.projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'xkcd-image',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent: pbm.vars.extent
});

/**
 * initMap
 * --------
 * triggered by pbm.parseCases!
 * outputs the bodymap to the #body-div
 * this functions needs all the other ol-elements to work!
 */
pbm.initMap = function(){  
  pbm.map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
          url: 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/norvell-philips/bodymap-static-hiress.jpg',
          projection: pbm.vars.projection,
          imageExtent: pbm.vars.extent
        })
      })
    ],
    target: 'body',//Div#body
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: pbm.vars.projection,
      center: ol.extent.getCenter(pbm.vars.extent),
      zoom: 2,
      maxZoom: 5,
      minZoom: 1,
      extent: pbm.vars.extent
    }),
    renderer: 'canvas',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({attribution:false, rotate: false, zoom:false}),
    interactions: pbm.vars.interactions
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    pbm.initMap();
});
```

Comment: Create a plunker example. It will help us to solve your issue?

Comment: I've added some code & a jsfiddle example

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that was recently fixed. The first release to contain the fix will be v3.21.0. The ticket with links to the fixes is [#5824](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/5824).